# LabVIEW: view every time a button is pressed

Tags: button, timestamp, labview

I’m trying to make a simple project to practice with LabVIEW:
I’m creating a VI with a standard Button and a stop button.
When the VI is running, I’ clicking the button many times and then, when I click on STOP, I would visualize on Front Panel a “List” (I’m using an array for this) which contain a timestamp for every button pression.

Is it possible? How can I do this?
I’m trying to create an array with the “insert into array” element, but it doesn’t seem to work..
Thank you all guys!

Comment: Are you using shift registers to update the array iteration after iteration? Can you post an image of your current state to clarify what you're trying to do? It's easier for us to give guidance if you show the code you've got so far.

Comment: PS: As for "is this possible", yes. LabVIEW is a programming language. It is as complete as any other programming language. Getting the time at which a button is pushed and then displaying the list is definitely within its abilities. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This does what you request. Two frames of the event structure and an autoindexing array collecting only the timestamps from the OK button press frames.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Thank you, it works! And what about if i had an array of Cluster, in which every cluster contain a Timestamp and a numeric indicator? (For example: at every button press I want to store the timestamp and the constant '5' in the array). I've tried "bundle" and many other array's operations, but I'm not unserstanding how does they work.

Comment: Every wire is an independent variable. When you bundle two wires together, you create a cluster that has both of the original values. You can build those into an array, and now you have an array of clusters. So, for your question, just add a bundle node after the Get Date node and bundle a 5 into the second input. Then delete the indicator and create a new indicator off of the tunnel terminal.

Comment: PS: if my answer works, please mark it as the accepted solution by clicking the checkmark to the left of my answer. That way everyone else knows this question has been answered and doesn't spend time answering it. Thanks, and welcome to Stack Exchange.