# LabVIEW: Save the timestamp of different button press time

Tags: button, timestamp, labview

I have a VI file in LabVIEW. In the UI I have several button which controls the speed of a fan.

[image]

[image]

"AUS" turns off the fan whereas STUFE1, STUFE2, STUFE3 are the different speed of a fan.
I want to get the timestamp saved in a excel file whenever a user presses each button. The output should be the following:

| Timestamps | Button |
| --- | --- |
| 5:24:10 PM 5/6/2022 | STUFE3 |
| 5:32:46 PM 5/6/2022 | STUFE1 |
| 6:10:10 PM 5/6/2022 | AUS |

I have tried to follow this  [stackoverflow solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72147104/labview-view-every-time-a-button-is-pressed) but I can follow it in my case. Since I am new to LabVIEW, I am not also familiar with the blocks too.

Comment: The solution you've found is a very good place to start. Unfortunately, I can see that your code is not well written and it's difficult to work on it. First, I would recommend you to preview some examples and learn how to refactor your code. Then, play with the solution you've found and modify it to save output to an excel file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you have to build a log file. Excel file is mandatory or you can use a CSV file?
Notice that CSV can be open with Excel too.

However, you should:

- add an event for each button: AUS value change, Stufe1 value change, etc...
- Every time one of these events occurs, you save the timestamp in your log file.

NOTE:
As suggested by Mateusz, you should refactor your code. I suggest you to move the code that is outside of the event structure inside the Timeout event.

Here is my suggestion. Consider that there are other more efficient ways. This is one of the simplest solutions.
You can drag and drop the image below in your LV Block diagram in order to view the entire code.
[image]